# What information can Uniprot give me about phosphorylated forms of proteins?

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, phosphorylation

I have a list of proteins formatted like this:

```
Protein Name        Gene Name
4E-BPI              EIF4EBP1
4E-BPI_pS65         EIF4EBP1
4E-BPI_PT37_T46     EIF4EBP1
53BP1               TP53BP1
```

Its my job to pull the following from [Uniprot](http://www.uniprot.org/):

- Subcellular Location information (this is easy)
- Information about phosphorylated forms

The first thing I did was compile a list of Uniprot IDs for each gene's human form that I could plug into the Upload List function.

Next, I used Uniprot's "Customize Results Table" [page](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=EIF4EBP1&sort=score#customize-columns), to add the "Subcellular Location" column to the output. **Do you know columns will provide information about the phosphorylated forms of these proteins?** I added columns PTM > PhosSite and PTM > PhosphoSite but they return the Uniprot ID or nothing at all.

**Is there somewhere else in Uniprot that I can look for information about phosphorylated forms of proteins?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were looking in the wrong spot. The PTM section you clicked on is for post-translational modification databases such as [PhosphoSite](http://www.phosphosite.org). To get the actual modified residues, click on "PTM/Processsing" (*sic*) further up the page and then select "Modified Residue", and in your results table you'll get a list of all phosphorylations, glycosylations, acetylations, etc.

Comment: [This](http://www.uniprot.org/help/mod_res) is the relevant help entry, should you want more information on these annotations. You can use the advanced search with Keyword '597' to only retrieve proteins that have phosphorylation annotations.